# Search inside an array and return multiple results

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have made this simple search snippet. I made it to search throughout my array(elements array) and if the input value is exactly equal to one of the element's names and that element will return.

So here if we search 'apple' in the input field the below result will return

{
color: "red",
name: "apple"
}

**My question is:** Without returning according to the exact value of the input, can we return a value like the input value. For example, instead of typing 'apple' word when we type the starting letters of the 'apple' word like 'ap' I'm expecting to return apple object and apex object which includes 'ap' (I want to return all the objects which contain the name like 'ap' from the array) like a normal search function does. Thank you if somebody likes to help me.Below is my code.

```js
//array
const elements = [{name: 'apple',color: 'red'},{name: 'apex', color: 'white'},{name: 'bat', color: 'black'}];

//find function
const searchElement = (elementsArray,keyword) => {
   const returnedElement = elementsArray.find((element,index) => {
      return element.name.toLowerCase() === keyword.toLowerCase();
   });
   
   return returnedElement;
}

//keyup event
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  const keyword = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  const result = searchElement(elements,keyword);
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="myInput">
```

Comment: You'll first have to define what you mean by "name *like* 'app'". According to your example, it's not just a partial match.

Comment: You're looking for "fuzzy search", for which there are loads of libraries out there. I don't think it's something that can properly be answered here, in a way that's on-topic for Stack Overflow, though.

Comment: Still unclear though. `apex` does not start with `app`.

Comment: But it does start with `ap`, which, again, is something __"Fuzzy search"__ libraries can match.

Comment: question updated again sorry its 'ap'

Comment: You did not explained: *starts-with* or *includes*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Use filter instead of it.

```js
//array
const elements = [
    { name: "apple", color: "red" },
    { name: "apex", color: "white" },
    { name: "bat", color: "black" }
];

//find function
const searchElement = (elementsArray, keyword) => {
    const returnedElement = elementsArray.filter((element, index) => {
        return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase());
    });

    return returnedElement;
};

//keyup event
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", () => {
    const keyword = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    const result = searchElement(elements, keyword);
    result.forEach((item) => console.log(item.name));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="myInput">
```

Comment: Use the `"input"` event instead of `"keyup"`. Copy/paste... remember?

Comment: Probably `startsWith()` is what OP is looking for instead of `includes()`.

Comment: Use `evt.currentTarget.value` instead of querying again the DOM

Comment: And no need to include `index` in the callback since you're not using it anyway. And probably should just immediately destructure `element` to `{name}`.

Comment: @BelugaB69 this seems not what you were looking for, since it uses `.includes` instead of `.startsWith()` - which was your question requirement (after the edit) - but yeah, it's an easy fix

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I think my solution can help you

```
const elements = [{name: 'apple',color: 'red'},{name: 'apex', color: 'white'},{name: 'bat', color: 'black'}];

//find function
const searchElement = (elementsArray,keyword) => {
   var result = [];
   
   elementsArray.forEach((element,index) => {
      if (element.name.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
            result.push(element);
      }
   });
   
   return result;
}

//keyup event
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  const keyword = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  const result = searchElement(elements,keyword);
  console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const elements = [{name: 'apple',color: 'red'},{name: 'apex', color: 'white'},{name: 'bat', color: 'black'}]
const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput')

myInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  const keyword = myInput.value.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
  const filterFn = ({ name }) => name.match(new RegExp(keyword, 'i'))
  const result = elements.filter(filterFn)
  
  console.clear()
  console.log(result)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="myInput">
```

Comment: All fun and games until someone puts a dot (`.`) in the input field. Now you got everything matching. Or a backslash (`\\`). Now you got an error. Or another character with special meaning in regular expression... [*"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RegExp expression:

```
const searchElement = (elementsArray, keyword) => {
    const returnedElement = elementsArray.find((element) => {
        return element.name.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp('.*' + keyword.toLowerCase() + '.*','i')) !== null;
    });
    return returnedElement;
}
```

If you use the RegExp expression `RegExp('.*' + keyword.toLowerCase() +'.*', 'i')`, pp will match 'apple'. If you use `RegExp('^' + keyword.toLowerCase() + '.*', 'i')` pp will not match apple but app will.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the `"input"` EventName (instead of `"keyup"`) - since an input value can change not only on some key event, but also when copy/pasting values into it, etc. The *"input"* event will handle all those cases.
- Inside the handler function, don't query again the DOM for your input element, simply use the *Event.currentTarget* like: `evt.currentTarget.value`
- Create a reusable function namely *`filter()`* that accepts four arguments: the Array to search, the Property name (key) to lookup, the String to search for, and an optional Object of options for case sensitive and match criteria (any position, full match, start or end of string)
- Use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) inside of your [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
/**
 * @param {string} str String to escape
 * @returns {string} String with escaped regex special characters
 */
const regEscape = (str) => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");

/**
 * @param {array} arr Array (of objects) to filter
 * @param {string} key Property name
 * @param {string} val Value to match
 * @param {object} opt Options for case sensitive and match criteria
 * @returns {array} Filtered array of objects
 */
const filter = (arr, prop, val, opt = {sensitive: false, match: "any"}) => {
  val = regEscape(val);
  const criteria = {
    any: val,
    start: `(?<=^| )${val}`,
    end: `${val}(?=$| )`,
    full: `(?<=^| )${val}(?=$| )`,
  }[opt.match];
  const reg = new RegExp(criteria, opt.sensitive ? "g" : "ig");
  return arr.filter(ob => reg.test(ob[prop]));
};


// Task: Search objects by "name" property

// Data:
const data = [
  {name: "apple", color: "red"},
  {name: "apexx", color: "white"},
  {name: "batle", color: "black"},
];

// Search input handler:
document.querySelector("#myInput").addEventListener("input", (evt) => {
  const results = filter(data, "name", evt.currentTarget.value, { match: "start" });
  console.clear()
  console.log(results)
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

as you can see above the option `{ match: "start" }` is used - which will make sure that the match should start at the beginning of string.
If you want to search from *"any"* position, use `{ match: "any" }` or remove the options, since "any" is by default.
To search case-sensitive use: `{ match: "start", sensitive: true }`

PS: Some of the used logic is taken from: [Hilite](https://github.com/rokobuljan/hilite)